# Lint warnings: leading zeroes and increment/decrement operators

Tags: javascript

I have some code that is not passing lint.  Is there is a better way to do this?

The first error is

> lint warning: leading zeros make an octal number

```
function getNumberCounter(lastNumberString, simple){
    var myCount;
    if(!lastNumberString){
        return "-1";
    }
    else{
        switch(lastNumberString.split("-")[1]){
            case "08" : myCount = 9;
                    break;
            case "09" : myCount = 10;
                break;
            case "99" : myCount = 00;
            break;
    default   : myCount = parseInt((lastNumberString.split("-")[1]),10) + 1;
                    break;
        }
        if(!simple){
            if(myCount <= 9){
                return ('0' + myCount);
            }
        }
        return myCount;
    }
}
```

and the other one is

> lint warning: increment (++) and decrement (--) operators used as part of greater statement

```
function getRandomString(_length){
    _retString = "";
    _charSet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    while(_length--){
        _retString += _charSet.charAt(Random(0, _charSet.length-1));
        Delay(1);
    }
    return _retString;
}
```

also this is javascript but it is not html type does anyone know what type it is, tried to use a javascript checker and it wants me to write html based code.

why is this happening and does it have an actual impact on the software I am using on my computer.

Comment: I put all the code into a fiddle and clicked JSHint - it first gave one error (leading 0). I changed the "00" to "0" and it gave no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many languages, a number with a leading zero is considered to be a octal (i.e. base 8) literal, apart from `0` itself.  For example `012` is the decimal number ten, even though it looks more like twelve.  So `00` is considered to be an octal number, although it's obviously zero.

Octal literals are however a syntax error in strict mode, as [octal numbers were never part of the ECMAScript standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).  I imagine your linter is enforcing the same rule.

So the fix to your first problem is simple:

```
    case "99" : myCount = 0;   // Drop one of the zeroes.
```

The second problem is here:

```
while(_length--){
```

You are decrementing the value of length **and also** reading either its original or new value.  Your linter is complaining because you are doing both.  Doing so makes for code that is difficult to read.  In particular, does the loop run `length` times or `length - 1` times?  It's not clear.

Your `while` loop always runs a fixed number of times, so from a stylistic point of view you would be better off with a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    _retString += _charSet.charAt(Random(0, _charSet.length-1));
    Delay(1);
}
```

As you're now only using `++` in the `++i` statement within the `for` loop, this *should* avoid lint warnings.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was thinking, I used some examples for this and was wondering if the 0 could be dropped and why the other expression was not written the way you propose, appreciate the assist. It greatly helps me on my learning path.

Comment: thank you a ton for the reference material, also any chance you can answer this question for me. I tried to use fiddle and other things like that and it asks me what library I want to use, I have no idea what to pick can you guide me on that.

Comment: @user330501: libraries are additional JavaScript code that you can download and use.  For example, jQuery is a library that a lot of people use.  That option in jsFiddle loads the jQuery library without you having to load it manually in your fiddle.  It doesn't look to me as if you're using any libraries, so the 'No-library (pure JS)' option, which doesn't load any, would be the right one for you.

Comment: so is there a way to load the libs I have on my side, also, if I want to ask another question about scripting different than this one, should I start another post or just ask here.

Comment: @user330501: you should ask another question.  If somebody else has the same question as you, they would find your question much more easily if there was an actual question for it rather than it being hidden in the comments on another question.

Comment: I would like to send props out to Luke Woodward, direct, clear understanding, and most of all answered the question with information supporting the idea, I would also like to thank everyone else who has almost got me kicked off here in less than 24 hours. It is amazing how my first noob use of the web site and a poorly worded  question allowed you guys to rank me down so fast and violently that I get warnings that I am about to be kicked.